# How to get Test and Production values for Fabric crashlytics?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I used the plugin to install Crashlytics for both iOS and Android applications. The one difference I noticed comes on the portal that Fabric provides. For iOS there are two environments, one Test (green icon) and the other Production (normal icon). Android does not do this.

[image]

I attempted to create two different environments by adding the following in my Application class

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
if (Constants.DEBUG) {
   Crashlytics.setString("version", "Production");
} else {
   Crashlytics.setString("version", "Test");
}
```

I thought this would create two different version but it did not do anything. How to create multiple environments for Android? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between release and debug other than signature in Android. So I don't think that would separate the products there. But what I did is, I've two flavors, one is `dev` and the other one is the `main` flavor which goes to Google Play.

`Dev` flavor has a different package name, which creates two different products in Fabric itself,  you don't need to do anything If you separate them with their package names.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something with flavors.

You can use something like this:

```
root
 app
  src
    main
      java
        package
        Application.java
    debug
      java
        CrashLyticsSetup.java
    release
      java
        CrashLyticsSetup.java
```

In your Application:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
CrashLyticsSetup.install(this);
```

In `debug/CrashLyticsSetup`:

```
public static void install(Application app){
  //do something
  Crashlytics.setString("version", "Test");
  //....
}
```

In `relaese/CrashLyticsSetup`:

```
public static void install(Application app){
  //do something
  Crashlytics.setString("version", "Production");
  //....
}
```

Of course you can customize it, with other flavors and other settings.
Also if you would like to disable CrashLytycs on debug you can use:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                    .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    .build())
            .build());
```